# VBA - Download PDF/Work Hyperlink from one Column and then Rename file to other column data

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, one with names and other with hyperlinks.
I can run VBA to download hyperlink but i want to rename the file based on the column's name -

```
Sub BatchOpenHyperLinks_SelectedRanges()
        Dim objSelectedRange As Excel.Range
        Dim objHyperlink As Excel.Hyperlink
    
        'Get selected ranges
        Set objSelectedRange = Excel.Application.Selection
        For Each objHyperlink In objSelectedRange.Hyperlinks
            objHyperlink.Follow
        Next
    End Sub
```

Can please someone help me to extend this code to rename file? - Thank you.